# Return a property from an object found using a delegate searching for a different property?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

So, after this wonderful and probably impossible to understand title, here is my problem.
I have this Button object:

```
class Button
{
    public Texture2D Texture {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

I'm holding a list of all the buttons in a `List<Button> buttons`. At some point in the code, I need to return the Texture property from a Button. I can't be sure of the value of it, so I can't search the button from it's Texture value. I need to search its name. I'm currently using a delegate:

```
SomeMethod(buttons.Find(delegate (Button btn) 
{
    return btn.Name = "Title";
}));
```

However, I can't return the Texture property this way, unless I create a temporary Button object.

So, how would I return the Texture property, by searching it by its Name ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
Texture2D theTexture = buttons
                        .Where(b => b.Name = "Title")
                        .Select(b => b.Texture)
                        .First();
```

If you want to handle "no matches", you can use `.FirstOrDefault()`, which will cause it to return null if there is no matching Name.

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

```
Texture2D t = buttons.Where(x => x.Name == givenName).Select(x => x.Texture).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can ensure that you always have the one you're searching for you could even do it with less.......

```
var tex = buttons.First(x => x.Name == givenName).First().Texture;
```